# UITapGestureRecognizer - detect double OR triple tap?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a case in which 2 completely different behaviors need to take place from a double-tap and a triple-tap on a particular view.  I set it up very standard, with the code below:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizerDoubleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(doubleTapDetected:)];
[gestureRecognizerDoubleTap setNumberOfTapsRequired:2];
[self.theView addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizerDoubleTap];

UITapGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizerTripleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tripleTapDetected:)];
[gestureRecognizerTripleTap setNumberOfTapsRequired:3];
[self.theView addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizerTripleTap];
```

The problem I am having is that if a triple-tap is done, the double-tap method is fired as well, since it detects the 2 taps before the 3rd.  So upon a triple-tap, both methods are called.

Obviously this isn't an inherent issue with the code or underlying SDK, since it's fully expected.  However, I'm curious if anyone has a clever way to somehow prevent the double-tap functionality to be called if a triple-tap is done?  I am assuming I may have to set the double-tap functionality on a delayed timer maybe (which would wait a split second to confirm whether a triple-tap is done), but I'm not sure if there's a better way, or even the best way to set this kind of thing up in a clean fashion?

Thanks in advance for any advice you can offer on this!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `requireGestureRecognizerToFail:` for this problem:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizerTripleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tripleTapDetected:)];
[gestureRecognizerTripleTap setNumberOfTapsRequired:3];
[self.theView addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizerTripleTap];

UITapGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizerDoubleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(doubleTapDetected:)];
[gestureRecognizerDoubleTap requireGestureRecognizerToFail:gestureRecognizerTripleTap];
[gestureRecognizerDoubleTap setNumberOfTapsRequired:2];
[self.theView addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizerDoubleTap];
```

The double-tap one won't fire unless the triple-tap one fails.

[The class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIGestureRecognizer/requireGestureRecognizerToFail%3a), as usual, has some additional information, and mentions this scenario as a great time to use this method.

Comment: Brilliant!  I was actually unaware of this method.  I added this code in, and right out of the box it works perfectly and as expected, with only one additional line of code from my original attempt.  Wonderful solution, thank you!

Comment: The most useful answer I have ever ran into in stack-overflow

Answer (score 1):

How about creating 2 recognizers, for 1 and 2 taps respectively (configure them via `numberOfTapsRequired`). This would obviously take care of detecting 1 and 2 taps. To detect 3 taps, you can check if the 1-tap recognizer has been fired immediately after the 2-tap one.

---

BTW, while I don't know what your application does, having both a triple and a double tap gestures seems like a potential usability concern. A triple tap by itself is not a commonly known way to interact with an app. I would at least consider a long press instead of a triple tap. That would completely sidestep this technical challenge :)

Comment: Interesting solution.  I'll give that a try and let you know.  And about your second point, I FULLY agree.  This is a requirement from the client, and even after some attempted push-back, it's something they really want, so we're stuck with having to implement.. :(  Thanks for the potential solution!